# Does every subgroup admit a biggest subgroup in which it is contranormal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

A subgroup $H$ of a group $S$ is contranormal if the normal closure of $H$ in $S$ is the whole group $S$.

If $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, does there exists a biggest subgrpup $S \subset G$ such that $H$ is a contranormal subgroup of $S$?

Comment: Take $S$ to be the normal closure of $H$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen If you take $H$ to be one of the [order two subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Properties) that lie inside one of the Klein subgroups of $D_4$, then the $S$ you suggest is the corresponding Klein that contains it. However, $H$ is normal in $S$ (and $H\neq S$). Therefore, not contranormal in $S$.

Comment: It is in fact the first idea to take $S = [H]_G$ = normal closure of $H$ in $G$. However, in general $[H]_G$ which is generated by all elements $ghg^{-1}$ with $g \in G$ is not the same as $[H]_S$ with $S \subset G$. The example given by orole demonstrates this. If the desired $S$ exists, then it must be generated by the union of all subgroups $S' \subset G$ such that $[H]_{S'} = S'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

Let $C$ be the set of subgroups $S'$ of $G$ for which $H$ is a contranormal subgroup of $S'$.

Let $S=\langle S'|S'\in C\rangle$. We show $H$ is contranormal in $S$, so as each $S'$ is contained in $S$, $S$ is the desired subgroup.

Consider the normal closure $H^{S}$ of $H$ in $S$. For each $S'\in C$, $S'=H^{S'}\subseteq H^S$ so $H^S$ contains each $S'$ and therefore $S$.

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen this by myself ;-)