# Are contranormally closed subgroups normal subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

This question is a sequel of

[Does every subgroup admit a biggest subgroup in which it is contranormal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2593454/349785)

Each subgroup $H$ of $G$ has a contranormal closure $\overline{H}$ which is defined as the biggest subgroup $S$ of $G$ such that the normal closure of $H$ in $S$ is the whole group $S$. Call $H$ contranormally closed if $\overline{H} = H$. Clearly normal subgroups are contranormally closed. I would be interested in an example which is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: How about a non-normal subgroup of order $2$ in the dihedral group of order $8$?

Comment: You are right - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formal answer based on Derek Holt's comment. Let $D_8$ be the dihedral group of order $8$ which has the presentation $\langle x, a \mid a^4 = x^2 = xax^{-1}a = e \rangle $. Let $K = \lbrace e, x, a^2, a^2x \rbrace$ which is one of the Klein groups of order $4$ sitting in $D_8$ and let $C = \lbrace e, x \rbrace$ which is a non-normal subgroup of $D_8$. Then $C, K, D_8$ are the only subgroups of $D_8$ containing $C$. Since $C$ is normal in $K$ and $K$ is normal in $D_8$, $C$ is the only subgroup in which $C$ is contranormal.

This is tightly connected to the answer of my question "Morphisms with zero cokernel".