# Is being a contranormally closed subgroup a transitive property?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

This question is related to

[Are contranormally closed subgroups normal subgroups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594486/are-contranormally-closed-subgroups-normal-subgroups)

where one can also find the definition of a contranormally closed subgroup.

Given a group $G$, a contranormally closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ and a contranormally closed subgroup $K$ of $H$, is $K$ a contranormally closed subgroup of $G$? I conjecture that this is in general not true (similar as for normal subgroups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this property is transitive. Let $L$ be the contranormal closure of $K$ in $G$. Then the normal closure of $H$ in $\langle H,L \rangle$ contains $H$ and $L$, and so is equal to $\langle H,L \rangle$.

But then since $H$ is contranormally closed in $G$, we get $\langle H,L \rangle=H$, so $L \le H$, and hence, since $K$ is contranormally closed in $H$, $L=K$.

Incidentally, for finite groups I think that a subgroupis contranormally closed if and only if it is subnormal.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Comment: In that case you should accept (and probably upvote) the answer.

Comment: You are right again, sorry that I forgot to do that!